# How do I verify the presence of an image by Katalon Studio?

Tags: automated-tests, katalon-studio

I have the following line of code in my program to verify that the element is an image:

```
if (WebUI.verifyImagePresent(findTestObject('Co-Sponsor Sign Up/Account Information/SponsorLogo'), FailureHandling.CONTINUE_ON_FAILURE)) {
WebUI.takeScreenshot()
}
```

When I run it, it returns the following error:

```
<TestCaseName>FAILED because (of) Unable to verify image present (Root cause: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This object don't have IMAGE_FILE property, please add it)
```

I have specified the object to be located by the xpath of the image:

```
/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/span/a/img
```

What I am doing wrong? What do I need to locate the image by?

Answer (score 0):

To use verifyImagePresent, you have to set both Object's Properties for Object (Id, XPath, class...) and the Image file at the "Image" field to compare. You can see the screenshot below:

[Screenshot link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbKd3.png)

Then you can use the keyword as normal command:

```
WebUI.verifyImagePresent(findTestObject("Page_HTML Images/img_workplace"))
```